# NoClassDefFoundError when a package name is defined in the class that has main()

Tags: java, terminal, noclassdeffounderror

Directory structure:

```
ClassOne.java
ClassOne.class
/dir
    ClassTwo.java
    ClassTwo.class
```

I'm purely using the terminal for this one. I compile both using `javac` to generate the class files.

ClassOne.java

```
import dir.ClassTwo;

public class ClassOne{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClassTwo two = new ClassTwo();
        two.printIt();
    }
}
```

ClassTwo.java

```
package dir;

public class ClassTwo {
    void printIt() {
        System.out.println("I am class two!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Running ClassOne.java works as intended (compiler error due to ClassTwo.printIt() being set to default). However, what stumped me is the `NoClassDefFoundError` that I get when I ran ClassTwo.

I noticed the error when I added the `package dir;` statement at the top - without it, ClassTwo runs as intended but ClassOne gets an error.

This is the error I get when I run ClassTwo with `package dir;` defined:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ClassTwo (wrong name: dir/ClassTwo)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the package name is part of the class name. Go up a folder and run it with something like

```
java -cp . dir.ClassTwo
```

Comment: So when running Java apps from the command line, I must make sure that I'm running it in the correct directory huh?

Comment: You need to include the root package in your classpath, and you need to specify the fully-qualified class name. If you do both of those, you may run it from any directory.